# About join/update/insert SQL query

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, sql-update

I am working on making a new SQLite database. Obviously for a number of reasons, structure and organization is important.

I have an existing database that is everything that I need, *except* for one column. So I duplicated the original db, and would like to just swap out that one column with new data from a different column in a different table in the db?

Can I do that? Which query is going to let me do that?

The join query just joins temporarily, right? If I need it to physically make the change in the db structure, do I use update?

I don't have tremendous amounts of experience with SQL queries, so any help here would be appreciated very much!

Comment: @Jared: I have added some line-breaks to your question, I think this makes it much easier to read. Hope you agree :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your table structure, this will be the way to go:

```
UPDATE new_table
SET new_column = ( SELECT old_column
                   FROM old_table
                   WHERE old_table.id = new_table.id )
```

It updates `new_column` in your `new_table` with the value of `old_table.old_column`, where the `id` column matches.

You can replace the `WHERE` clause in the sub-select by whatever you have to find correlating records.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create a query and insert it into your new structure.  I'm assuming there is some kind of link between the 2 tables that you need to get the data from?

```
INSERT INTO TableName (field1, field2, field3) 
(SELECT field1, field2, Field3
FROM SomeTable 
INNER JOIN OtherTable on SomeTable.KeyField = OtherTable.FKField)
```